# Sesame Server authentication on Jetty

Tags: authentication, jetty, sesame

I am trying to configure authentication for Sesame Server 2.7.10 (problem reproduced on Sesame Server 2.9) on Jetty 8.1.9. The authentification works when I try to access the URL http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/toto but fails while I am trying to connect to the repository via Sesame WorkBench. The following error is displayed after editing server (http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/), user and password (see screen capture below "Sesame WorkBench repository user login"):

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /openrdf-workbench/repositories/toto/server. Reason:

    Unconfigured path: /server

Caused by:

org.openrdf.workbench.exceptions.BadRequestException: Unconfigured path: /server
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ProxyRepositoryServlet.service(ProxyRepositoryServlet.java:100)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:222)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.handleRequest(WorkbenchServlet.java:151)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:119)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.service(WorkbenchGateway.java:131)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.CookieCacheControlFilter.doFilter(CookieCacheControlFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image: Sesame WorkBench repository user login]

I added a bean on jetty.xml with a "SesameConfig" name:

```
<Call name="addBean">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
      <Set name="name">SesameConfig</Set>
      <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
      <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

I also defined users in /etc/realm.properties:

```
totoeditor: password,toto-editor
totoviewer: password,toto-viewer
```

Those users have roles defined in /webapps/openrdf-sesame/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Sesame TOTO repository: SPARQL query access</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/repositories/toto</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>toto-viewer</role-name>
    <role-name>toto-editor</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Sesame TOTO repository viewer access</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/repositories/toto/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>toto-viewer</role-name>
    <role-name>toto-editor</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Sesame TOTO repository: editor write access</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/repositories/toto/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
    <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>toto-editor</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Sesame server configuration</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <description>
        The role that is required to access the Sesame server configuration
    </description>
    <role-name>sesame-admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
<description>
    The role that is required for read access to the TOTO repository
</description>
<role-name>toto-viewer</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
<description>
    The role that is required for write access to the TOTO repository
</description>
<role-name>toto-editor</role-name>
</security-role>    

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Do you have any idea of what goes wrong ?
Thanks,

Comment: "[...] fails while I am trying to connect to the repository via Sesame WorkBench" - fails _how_? Are you getting any errors? Can you [edit] your question to show what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Error message added, thanks.

Comment: Very odd. Deleted my earlier answer, since that clearly wasn't the problem. I'll take a closer look later. As an aside though: 2.7.10 is quite an old version of Sesame. Can you try upgrading to a newer version to check if the problem is still there?

Comment: I use Sesame with the Ontop plugin, which could be downloaded in a bundle with this old version of Sesame. But I will try to use Sesame 2.9 and I give you a feedback. Thanks,

Comment: I reproduced the problem with Sesame 2.9.